# Render JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jruby

I want to see the following code in json format.  When I do so I get a blank page with no content.  In the rubymine debugger I have the correct information in json format.

```
include Java

require 'net/http'

class PatientRecordController < ApplicationController

  def index
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/patient/record/v2/'
    data_raw = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body

    @data_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(data_raw)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render json: @data_json}
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You must add `.json` at the end of the path you enter into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What is the path to this particular `index` action? This code should indeed render JSON, which your debugger is indicating that it indeed is.

The URL you should be visiting is something akin to `http://your_host/patient_records/index.json`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the request to include .json, you can just drop the respond_to block `render json: @data_json` on its own will work.